# Cursor within a cursor

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursors

I need your help.
I am trying to make a series of cursors within other cursors.
Below I show you the tables with which I want to make the cursors.

[image]

First make the cursor of the first table looking for record.
Second, in table 1 we have the column "ID_ASI", with that column I want to make another cursor that searches inside another table (IMAGE OF TABLE 2) all the "ID_ASI" that it finds with the same "ID_ASI".

[image]

Finally, the "ID_ASI" finding by the second step, make a new cursor that looks for all "ID_DOC" that have the same "ID_ASI".
For example,
In the second step, when making the cursor in the "ID_ASI" column, find 3 rows with the same "ID" (101), then the third step searches for all "ID_DOC" with the same "ID_ASI".
For example, "ID_ASI" 101 has 3 "ID_DOC" (value 10), 101 has 2 other values ​​(20) and finally two other values ​​(30).
The complicated thing is how to group them all in the same way, and how to put a cursor inside a cursor.

This would be the result.

[image: IMAGE OF TABLE 2 RESULTS]

Thank you for attention.

Comment: Do you have to use cursors ? Usually `a cursor whithin another cursor` means some kind of task that can be done using plain SQL with a simple join or a subquery, and this SQL will be about 40~50 times faster than cursors.

Comment: Do you mean [`cursor()` expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CURSOR-Expressions.html), or joins? How will this be used? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I had already tried to do this with a Join, but it does not group all the "ID_DOC", I made an example like Bob's answer.

Comment: A join isn't the same thing as a cursor within a cursor, so I'm still not clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like what you want is to join the tables together, something like

```
SELECT t2.*
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
  INNER JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t2.ID_ASI = t1.ID_ASI
  ORDER BY t2.ID_ASI, t2.ID_DOC
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1246a/3)

Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, I had already tried to do this with a Join, but it does not group all the "ID_DOC", if you see in the image 2, you will see that the ID_ASI 101 has the ID_DOC 10, 20, 30, but those do not all the ID_DOC 10, 20, 30.
I hope you understand.

Comment: I changed it around a bit - see [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c862f/6) but it doesn't duplicate the (104, 10, 500, NULL) row as you show in your results. Best of  luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfc1b/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 ( ID_ASI ) AS
  SELECT 101 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 301 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 (ID_ASI, ID_DOC, IMPORT, IMPORT_TO ) AS
  SELECT 101, 10, NULL, 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 20, NULL, 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 30, NULL, 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201, 23, NULL, 430 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 201, 23, 430, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 104, 10, 500, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 104, 20, 2000, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 104, 10, 500, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 104, 30, 3000, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE_2
START WITH ID_ASI IN ( SELECT ID_ASI FROM TABLE_1 )
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID_DOC = ID_DOC
AND PRIOR ID_ASI < ID_ASI
ORDER SIBLINGS BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dfc1b/1/0)**:

```
| ID_ASI | ID_DOC | IMPORT | IMPORT_TO |
|--------|--------|--------|-----------|
|    101 |     10 | (null) |      1000 |
|    104 |     10 |    500 |    (null) |
|    104 |     10 |    500 |    (null) |
|    101 |     20 | (null) |      2000 |
|    104 |     20 |   2000 |    (null) |
|    101 |     30 | (null) |      3000 |
|    104 |     30 |   3000 |    (null) |
|    201 |     23 |    430 |    (null) |
|    201 |     23 | (null) |       430 |
```

Comment: I have to create the table with from dual union all?
Because I tried like you wrote but did not give me the same results.